# Vue App environment variables can be read in development mode but not in production mode

Tags: firebase, vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli, dev-to-production

I am using the Vue cli to create a vue app with Firebase as my backend.

A file within my app initializes the Firebase DB by referring to environment variables that are defined in `.env` files.

`.env`

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=#################################
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=#################################
FIREBASE_DB_URL=https://#################################
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=#################################
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=#################################
FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=#################################
AUTH_API=https://#################################
```

`.env.development.local` and `.env.production.local` contain the same data.

Within my app I have a file that looks like this:

credentials.js

export default {

```
config: {
apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_DB_URL,
projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
}
```

}

When I serve the development version of this app using `yarn serve`, the database is initialized, so the .env variables are obviously read without a problem.  However, when I use `yarn build` and then serve the resulting files in `dist`, I get an error on the console:

```
 @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
```

Which is basically telling me that the environment variables are not being read in production mode.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "element-ui": "^2.12.0",
    "feather-icons": "^4.24.1",
    "firebase": "^7.2.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "node-ipc": "^9.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-feather": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-feather-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue2-animate": "^2.1.3",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuefire": "^2.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: I think that you need to prefix your variables with `VUE_APP_` in your `.env` files. From https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables : "Note that only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin"

Comment: @thibautg This seems to be an anwser! You should write it as an answer instead of just  a comment.

Comment: Done. I hope it will be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix your variables with `VUE_APP_` in your `.env` files.

From https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables:

> Note that only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`.

Comment: why would this be an issue for the build command and not for the serve command? The OP seems to be indicating that the env vars are working without the prefix when using the serve command

Comment: It may be because with `serve`, the variables are kept in memory with the built-in web server, but not necessarily with whatever server is used to serve the built bundle. If the vars are prefixed by `VUE_APP_`, they will be hard-coded in the resulting bundle. This is how I understand it though, I may be wrong.

Comment: ah that does makes sense